# Multiplying nested vec by scalar

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a nested `Vec<Vec<f64>>` in Rust, and I want to multiply each `f64` in place by a value `DT`. I am currently doing:

```
dcm_dot.iter_mut().map(|a| a.iter_mut().map(|b| * b * DT));
```

This works, however, I am getting a lazy iterator warning, that the .map()s must be consumed. Is there a more idiomatically correct way to do this?

Comment: The warning says "iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed", correctly. That code doesn't modify `dcm_dot` and is effectively a no-op. It's unidiomatic in the sense that it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators in Rust are lazy so unless you use the result of the `.map()`,
the closure inside will not even be executed.
In order to ensure that your code actually changes the `Vec`, you should use `.for_each()` instead.
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=51d64ca50b34a78101abef37292acc20)

Comment: Or better a `for` loop.